# capture QVideoFrame and display it in QVideoWidget

Tags: c++, qt5

I want capture from camera frames.
I setup ui, camera, and surface.

```
QtVideoWidgetsIssueTrack::QtVideoWidgetsIssueTrack(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

   
    QCamera* mCamera = new QCamera();
    QMediaRecorder* recorder = new QMediaRecorder(mCamera);
    QVideoEncoderSettings settings = recorder->videoSettings();
    QMyAbstractVideoSurface* surface = new QMyAbstractVideoSurface();
    

    settings.setResolution(640, 480);
    settings.setQuality(QMultimedia::VeryHighQuality);
    settings.setFrameRate(30.0);
    settings.setCodec("video/mp4");
    recorder->setVideoSettings(settings);
    recorder->setContainerFormat("mp4");

    mCamera->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureViewfinder);
   
    mCamera->setViewfinder(surface);

    // Set layout
    QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout();

    QVideoWidget* videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
 
    videoWidget->show();
    // Set layout in QWidget
    QWidget* window = new QWidget();
    layout->addWidget(videoWidget);
    window->setLayout(layout);

    // Set QWidget as the central layout of the main window
    setCentralWidget(window);

    
    bool o = recorder->setOutputLocation(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/" + "test_video"));
    recorder->record();
        
    mCamera->start();

    qDebug() << o;
    qDebug() << recorder->supportedVideoCodecs();
    qDebug() << recorder->state();
    qDebug() << recorder->error();
    qDebug() << recorder->outputLocation();
}

QtVideoWidgetsIssueTrack::~QtVideoWidgetsIssueTrack()
{}
```

I have created QMyAbstractVideoSurface instance and set surface in camera.

```
#pragma once
#include <QtMultimedia/QAbstractVideoSurface>
class QMyAbstractVideoSurface : public QAbstractVideoSurface
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QMyAbstractVideoSurface(QObject* parent = 0);
    ~QMyAbstractVideoSurface();

    QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat> supportedPixelFormats(QAbstractVideoBuffer::HandleType handleType) const;

    bool present(const QVideoFrame& frame);

    bool start(const QVideoSurfaceFormat& format);

    void stop();
};
```

Now the problem is capture QVideoFrame from present method and display it in QVideoWidget.
Then add QVideoWidget to grid layout.

```
#include "QMyAbstractVideoSurface.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QBuffer>

QMyAbstractVideoSurface::QMyAbstractVideoSurface(QObject* parent) {
}

bool QMyAbstractVideoSurface::start(const QVideoSurfaceFormat& format) {
    return QAbstractVideoSurface::start(format);

}

void QMyAbstractVideoSurface::stop() {
    QAbstractVideoSurface::stop();
}

bool QMyAbstractVideoSurface::present(const QVideoFrame& frame) {

    if (frame.isValid()) {
        QVideoFrame cloneFrame(frame);
        QAbstractVideoBuffer::HandleType handleType;
        cloneFrame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly);
        qDebug() << cloneFrame;

        const QImage image(cloneFrame.bits(),
            cloneFrame.width(),
            cloneFrame.height(),
            QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(cloneFrame.pixelFormat()));

        QByteArray ba;
        QBuffer bu(&ba);
        //bu.open(QBuffer::ReadWrite);
        bu.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        image.save(&bu, "PNG");
        //bu.close();
        //QString imgBase64 = ba.toBase64();
        QString imgBase64 = QString::fromLatin1(ba.toBase64().data());
        qDebug() << "image base64: " << imgBase64;

        cloneFrame.unmap();

        return true;
    }
    return true;
}

QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat> QMyAbstractVideoSurface::
supportedPixelFormats(QAbstractVideoBuffer::HandleType handleType) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(handleType);
    return QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat>()
        << QVideoFrame::Format_ARGB32
        << QVideoFrame::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied
        << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB32
        << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB24
        << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB565
        << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB555
        << QVideoFrame::Format_ARGB8565_Premultiplied
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGRA32
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGRA32_Premultiplied
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGR32
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGR24
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGR565
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGR555
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGRA5658_Premultiplied
        << QVideoFrame::Format_AYUV444
        << QVideoFrame::Format_AYUV444_Premultiplied
        << QVideoFrame::Format_YUV444
        << QVideoFrame::Format_YUV420P
        << QVideoFrame::Format_YV12
        << QVideoFrame::Format_UYVY
        << QVideoFrame::Format_YUYV
        << QVideoFrame::Format_NV12
        << QVideoFrame::Format_NV21
        << QVideoFrame::Format_IMC1
        << QVideoFrame::Format_IMC2
        << QVideoFrame::Format_IMC3
        << QVideoFrame::Format_IMC4
        << QVideoFrame::Format_Y8
        << QVideoFrame::Format_Y16
        << QVideoFrame::Format_Jpeg
        << QVideoFrame::Format_CameraRaw
        << QVideoFrame::Format_AdobeDng;
}

QMyAbstractVideoSurface::~QMyAbstractVideoSurface()
{}
```

it display me this

QVideoFrame(QSize(640, 480), Format_YUYV, NoHandle, ReadOnly, [no timestamp])

image base64:  ""